# Jquery .ajax() local testing

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, xmlhttprequest

I've got a little .ajax function which trying to load some content after document is ready.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$.ajax({
        url: 'php/accounts-blocks.php',
        cache: false,
        beforeSend: function() { $('#accounts-blocks').html('Please wait...'); },
        success: function(html) { $('#accounts-blocks').html(html); }
        });
});
```

However, when I'm trying to test this page locally (just on my PC), ajax shows up only "Please wait" message like forever, and doesn't load any content. Should I install local hosting or something like that in order to test AJAX functionality, or is it something wrong with script?

Comment: What does the developper toolbar shows on XHR request? What is the status of the request?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ajax (XHR) will not work in some browsers (there are exceptions such as Firefox) when running the script locally without having a local web server installed. Chrome is an example that will not allow it.

Use a browser with less strict security, or install a local HTTP server.

Comment: An example of easy to install local server: [XAMPP](https://www.apachefriends.org/index.html)