# How to list results from JSON using Ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax

I have my first Ajax code and I am a little bit confused how to get all values from certain

```html
<html>
<head>
  <script type="text/JavaScript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <title>My first Ajax</title>
</head>

<body>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    $(submit).click(function getResults() {
      return $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "https://www.cs.kent.ac.uk/people/staff/lb514/hygiene/hygiene.php",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        async: "true",
        cache: "false",
        success: function(msg) {
          // success          
        },
        Error: function(x, e) {
          // On Error
        }
      });
    });
    }
  </script>
  <input id="submit" name="submit" type="submit" value="Submit">
  </input>
</body>
</html>
```

url. Following papers I have made code down below, but it does nothing to be honest. I would like to know how can I list certain data from this url?

Comment: In both your success and error function, do a console.log(msg) and see what's the output.

Comment: You have a lot of issues here. 1) `async` and `cache` take boolean values, not strings 2) *Don't use `async: false`.* It is horrendous. If you check the console you'll even see the browser telling you not to use it. 3) It's `error`, not `Error` 4) remove `getResults` 5) Where is `submit` defined?

Comment: Got it, really good advices. I followed all them. I thought I could use directly html tags in there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's many things you need to change (most of them are reference here: http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/):

- Use a newer version of jquery:
  http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js
- JS snipper should come after the  element, as there's no element defined when JS executed
- $(submit) is invalid. It should be $('#submit') as valid selector.
- use evt.preventDefault() to prevent default browser behavior
- url: you can't make request on another domain unless that url has enabled CORS (cross origin resource sharing), otherwise the request will work only on the same domain as your page. See an option on how to test locally: [Jquery .ajax() local testing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23056935/jquery-ajax-local-testing)
- async: true -> that's default so you can ommit
- dataType -> that's fine if you expect JSON from server
- contentType -> that's fine, but you don't send anything to the server, so it's not really needed
- error: starts with lower letter

Here' the code updated:

```
    <html>
     <head>
          <script type="text/JavaScript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
          <title>My first Ajax</title>
    </head>
    <body>
    <input id="submit" name="submit" type="submit" value="Submit">

     <script type="text/javascript">
     $("#submit").click(function(evt) {
      evt.preventDefault();
      $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "https://www.cs.kent.ac.uk/people/staff/lb514/hygiene/hygiene.php",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        cache: "false",
        success: function(msg) {
          // success
        },
        error: function(x, e) {
          // On Error
        }
      });
    });
    </script>
    </body>
   </html>
```

Comment: You helped me a lot. :-)

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
$('#submit').click(function() {
       $.getJSON(url,function(data){
             // Do whatever you need
       });
});
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion. Please also try not to crowd your code with explanatory comments, this reduces the readability of both the code and the explanations!

Answer (score 0):

First of all, your script should be defined after input tag. Also, make sure you have proper headers to access the url or it will give error related to Access-Control-Allow-Headers.

Answer (score 0):

use loop for-in

```js
$(submit).click(function getResults() {
      return $.ajax({
      type: "GET",
      url:"https://www.cs.kent.ac.uk/people/staff/lb514/hygiene/hygiene.php",
      contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
      dataType: "json",
      async: "true",
      cache: "false",
      success: function (msg) {
                   for (var i in data){
                       // data[i].something, etc
               }        
            },
            Error: function (x, e) {
                // On Error
            }
      });
    });
```